# Como aprovar um modelo dependendo da confirmação de outro modelo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como faço para a `View` de solicitação só aparecer para o usuário, quando a confirmação da classe `Aprovacao` for `true`.

**Segue a lógica:**

1- usuário cria a solicitação e cadastra,

2- usuário aguarda a confirmação da solicitação feita

3- se a solicitação for aprovada

4- usuário consegue ver a solicitação cadastrada

**Models:**

```
public class Solicitacao
{
    public int SolicitacaoId { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }


    public string servico { get; set; }
}
```

Gostaria que esta classe confirmasse a solicitação

```
public class Aprovacao
{
    public  int AprovacaoId  { get; set; }


    public string Aprova { get; set; }

   public int SolicitacaoId { get; set; }

   public virtual Solicitacao _Solicitacao{ get; set; }

}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Solicitacao</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Servico, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Servico, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Servico, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Qual o método eu usaria para fazer essa confirmação na `controller` de Aprovação?

Comment: Bem vindo Elói Ferreira. Coloque também o código da sua `view`. Quando possível faça o [Tour] do site para entender melhor a comunidade.

Comment: Obrigado, @GeorgeWurthmann! Já adicionei a **View**

Comment: @ElóiFerreira Mas em que momento esta aprovação tem que ser feita, tem que ser aprovada por outro usuário do sistema? Este fluxo não está muito claro.

Comment: @EdneyBatistadaSilva No meu caso o usuário faz a solicitação e o adm aprova. Vi em alguns lugares que a solicitação teria que persistir no banco de qualquer forma, certo? E aí eu quero que a solicitação apareça salva na tela do usuário, somente quando o adm fazer está aprovação, antes disso quando persistir o cadastro da solicitação, aparecesse uma mensagem para o usuário para aguardar a aprovação do adm.

Answer (score 0):

Ao salvar sua solicitação você pode redirecionar o usuário para a tela com as listas de todas as solicitações:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Solicitacao solicitacao)
    {
        SeuRepositorio.SalvarSolicitacao(solicitacao);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Na view index você pode listar todas as solicitações abertas no sistema, e mostrar uma mensagem ao usuário de que existem solicitações que ainda não foram aprovadas.

Estas solicitações podem ser exibidas em uma tabela ordenada, exibindo os registros não aprovados no começo, ou mesmo as linhas de registros não aprovados  podem ser destacadas em vermelho.

Então na sua action Index ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Solicitacao> solicitacoes = SeuRepositorio.ObterTodasAsSolicitacoes();
        return View(solicitacoes);
    }
```

Estou presumindo que o campo status da solicitação é o que indique que ela está aprovada ou não.

Agora na sua View Index você cria a sua tabela, recomendo o uso do bootstrap para facilitar utilizar destacar as linhas:

```
@model List<AprovadorDeSolicitacoes.Models.Solicitacao>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Solicitacao</th>
        <th>#</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in this.Model)
    {
        <tr class="@(item.Status ? "success" : "danger")">
            <td>@item.SolicitacaoId </td>
            <td>@item.servico  </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/Solicitacao/Detalhes/@item.SolicitacaoId">detalhes</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Por sua vez no link de detalhes onde você redireciona para a action de detalhes você pode fazer outra validação e redirecionar o usuário para a view adequada:

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(int id)
    {
        var solicitacao = SeuRepositorio.AbrirSolicitacao(id);
        if(!solicitacao.Status)
            return View("ViewComMensagemDeNaoAprovado", solicitacao);
        return View(solicitacao); // manda para sua view que exibe os detalhes da solicitação já aprovada.
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Valeu @EdneyBatistadaSilva, vou tentar fazer a sua solução. Obrigado